# how do I let my program know and respond to a key being pressed

Tags: python-3.x

I am thirteen years old, and I am learning to code. I think that I am doing quite well, however, I have hit a massive roadblock. 
I am trying to program some sort of advanced Etch a sketch game, and with the general coding, I can do it.

like:
if the player says 'forward' + number:
  go forward by that number.

that all works and it can draw shapes and everything, and rub out and change color even.
But what I am trying to do, is make my program respond to going forward when the button 'w' 'a' 's' or 'd' buttons are pressed, then without clicking enter, have it immediately have a turtle move by 40 pixels up, down, left or right.

I am using a platform called Trinket.io and so far it is proving very useful to code on. but whenever I find a website that says, 'this should work!' it doesn't. or it is only a snippet of code, or whatever the problem is, the program won't respond when I click w a s or d.

On Trinket.io, when you open up a pygame trinket it gives you two example games that both work on w a s d movement. I have tried to take some code form that, and modify it so it will print some text 'you clicked a' or 'you clicked w'. This hasn't worked either.

By the way, all of this testing has been done on a completely different trinket so various bits of code in the Etch a sketch prodject can't be the problem.

```
from time import *
import pygame
pygame.init()

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

while True: # main game loop

  for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
    if event.type == K_DOWN:
      print('key down')
    elif event.key == K_UP:
      print('key up')
```

this piece of code is as close as I think I have gotten so far to my goal as it produces no error messages, it just doesn't work or do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your event handling loop in a different thread so it can run with your game:

```
from time import *
import pygame
import _thread
pygame.init()

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

def controller():
    while True: # main game loop
      for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
        if event.type == K_DOWN:
          print('key down')
        elif event.key == K_UP:
          print('key up')
_thread.start_new_thread(controller)
```

Your controller should be running parallel with your game, This means that **the rest of your game will also have to be put into it's own thread**

.
See this for more info on threading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: I just tried to do what you just said, however it says that there is not a modual named:    import  _thread, I clicked on your link, and it says as well that there should be a modual named _thread. do I need to install _thread? and if so, how do I do it.